# Wix Installer with WPF UI not running MSI

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, windows-installer

I am currently building a WiX project which is supposed to act as a delivery wrapper for other installers- this way I can make a msi for any project, wrap it in this project, and have a new installer.

At the moment, I am experimenting with a pair of very basic installers- when they install, they should create a folder and place four empty text files in the folder. The top level wxs file is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
    <Bundle Name="Jeremiah's Test Installer" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Starkey" UpgradeCode="5a714642-7857-4582-8bae-80fd6d8ec77a">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
      <Payload SourceFile="..\TestWPF003\BootstrapperCore.config"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="..\TestWPF003\bin\Release\TestWPF003.dll"/>
      <Payload SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.9\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
      <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx4Full' />      
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\beta\bin\Release\beta.msi"  Id="BetaInstallId" Cache="yes" Visible="yes"/>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\alpha\bin\Release\alpha.msi"  Id="AlphaInstallId" Cache="yes" Visible="yes"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>

  <Fragment>

    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx4Full" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />

    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full" Value="Version" Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion" Win64="yes" />

    <PackageGroup Id="Netfx4Full">
      <ExePackage Id="Netfx4Full" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes"
                  SourceFile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe"
                  DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)" />
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

The problem I am coming up against is that the UI will appear, the buttons will trigger, and an entry will be made in the Windows registry saying that the program has been installed. However, when I go to look for the files, nothing will be there. I can sweep my system for the file and folder names, but they will not be present anywhere. If I run the installers on their own, the folders are created and the files are present.

Edit: Installation Log - http://pastebin.com/cMFei9cr

Comment: So, I changed the Visibility to false and the Cache to always. I don't know why, but now it's installing. However, it still will not uninstall.

Comment: Please provide your bundle's installation log that's in the user's temp directory.

Comment: @sean-hall - added link to installation log

Answer (score 2):

According to the log, the bundle thinks that the packages are already installed so it doesn't try to install them again (`execute:None`).

```
Planned package: BetaInstallId, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
Planned package: AlphaInstallId, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
```

I don't know why there's so many related bundles:

```
Detected related bundle: {005cc4d6-ddbb-40e6-9b55-1e75c3fd93f7}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {062482ea-7e51-4d0d-bfdb-4da66a31c8d7}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {1c6dc0b9-8d20-4fcc-ba0f-88278407bfd7}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {27a27a66-9612-475b-b4c1-4b0154f2ffc1}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {284b58db-4377-4d3f-81f6-8683960062a8}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {4508d6e7-0b9d-44b5-8270-f5b2e4a9f1eb}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {616c17bc-349a-4fa4-a96d-44089a199e3d}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {85fd546d-8c91-44e1-9fcb-1a84e3727773}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {b48ca10f-ec2e-417e-91e2-d60a85cf08a3}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {c6450493-7e9e-4341-ab20-fece27d7f706}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {daefbdf5-330d-4ab7-b504-629c6d474142}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
Detected related bundle: {e3eb09bd-6c1e-4969-8298-450e0041d424}, type: Upgrade, scope: PerMachine, version: 1.0.0.0, operation: None
```

I bet it would work on a clean machine.

Comment: I'll give that a shot as soon as I can. I think I've got a VM I can spin up soon.

If I had a pile of installers that wouldn't uninstall, what's the best way to get rid of them? Should I just be able to delete the registry entries?